# how to create a keras layer that takes effect only during evaluation phase (and that is transparent during training)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want to add to my model a layer that, during evaluation, takes the input, applies some transformations (a quantization in this case, but can be whatever) and return it as the output. This layer must, however, be completely transparent during training, meaning that it must return the same input tensor.

I have written the following function

```py
from keras.layers import Lambda
import keras.backend as K

def myquantize(x):
    return K.in_test_phase( K.clip(K.round(x*(2**5))/(2**5),-3.9,3.9) , x)
```

which I then use via a Lambda layer

```py
y = keras.layers.Conv1D(**args1)
y = keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2)(y)
y = keras.layers.Lambda(myquantize)(y)
y = keras.layers.Conv1D(**args2)
#...
```

Now, in principle the K.in_test_phase should return x during training, and that expression during test.
However, training the network with such layer prevent the network from learning (i.e. the train loss stops decreasing after 3 epochs), while if I remove it the network keeps training normally. I assume this layer is not actually transparent during training as expected.

Comment: Have you checked if replacing the body of `myquantize` with `return x`, or `return K.identity(x)`, does allow the network to train successfully?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, replacing the function's return it with 'return x' let the network to train successfully

Answer (score 0):

[`in_test_phase`](https://keras.io/backend/#in_test_phase) has a parameter of `training` which you can explicitly set to indicate whether you are training or not. If you don't set it explicitly, then the value of [`learning_phase`](https://keras.io/backend/#learning_phase) is used. This value keeps changing when you reset the graph or when you call different types of fit/predict/evaluate functions of model.

Since your full code isn't present, you can make use of `training` parameter. Set it to True during training. Then save the weights of the model using [`save_weights`](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/#about-keras-models) function of model. When you wish to test your model, set the `training` parameter to False. Then load the weights using [`load_weights`](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/#about-keras-models) function and then you can proceed accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately as I am experimenting different architectures I cannot keep the code for generating each architecture, so I save/restore the model with model.save and keras.models.load_model. Therefore, I cannot change the training parameter during test, because when I restore the model I just get a pre-compiled graph which I cannot modify. (If I have well understood your question).
Anyway, in principle if I call 
y_test = model.predict_generator(test_seq, verbose=1)
this should set the learning_phase to false right?

Comment: And of course vice versa model.fit_generator(generator=train_sequence,**args) should set the flag to true

Answer (score -1):

For those who are in a similar situation, I created a custom layer like the following, which I only use during training:

```py
class MyLayer(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        x=inputs
        return K.identity(x)
```

note that this layer always returns the input tensor, but it serves as 'placeholder' for the next step. On the evaluation part of the code, I wrote the following code:

```py
class MyLayer(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        x=inputs
        return #Your actual processing here
```

Here, the only difference is that you actually perform the desired processing steps on your tensor. When I load my stored model, I pass this class as custom object

```py
model = keras.models.load_model(model_file,custom_objects={'MyLayer':MyLayer})
```

be careful to pass as MyLayer the one where the actual processing is performed.

This is my solution, other suggestions are welcome